# Install Docker on a specific volume

Tags: docker

Is there a way to install Docker on a specific volume ?

When I install Docker on Amazon Linux with the following command :

```
sudo yum install docker
```

and then start the docker service using :

```
sudo service docker start
```

It creates two Data Spaces :

- Data file: /dev/loop0
- Metadata file: /dev/loop1

How can I have those spaces be on a given volume such as `/mnt/docker` for example ?

Answer (score 1):

Those are **device files**. They will always be in `/dev` (actually not, but let's just assume for sake of simplicity, here). `loop0` and `loop1` are **loop devices** that are backed by the actual Docker volume files. You can easily see this using `losetup -l`:

```
> losetup -l
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE
/dev/loop0         0      0         1  0 /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
/dev/loop1         0      0         1  0 /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
```

What you might want to do (depending on your file system layout) is **moving the Docker runtime directory** somewhere else (default is `/var/lib/docker`; all Docker volumes and images are stored there). For this, you can supply the `-g` flag to the Docker daemon.

In **CentOS/Fedora/RHEL** (and probably, because it's based on RHEL, also **Amazon Linux**), you can modify the `/etc/sysconfig/docker` file for this (look for an `OPTIONS` variable). In **Ubuntu/Debian** `/etc/default/docker` would be the place to look.

Comment: Isn't there another way than moving the docker runtime directory ?

Comment: @Charlesthk, I'm still not sure what you're actually trying to *achieve*. Are you actually trying to move the *device files* to another location? If so, why? They're not taking up any disk space themselves. Forgive me for saying, but this looks like a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: my problem is that I installed docker with lot of images and ended up with a full disk with no more available space. The idea is to attach another disk and install docker and all of its images on that one. I didn't knew about the XY problem, nice concept ;-)

Comment: You want the -g option then, as I posted in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get docker to store all of its data (containers and their data volumes) at a different place in the file system (my EBS volume) by editing /etc/sysconfig/docker

which has the line:

```
OPTIONS="--default-ulimit nofile=1024:4096"
```

I added the -g option, as documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/)

```
OPTIONS="--default-ulimit nofile=1024:4096 --graph=/home/ec2-user/myvolume"
```

where myvolume is the directory where I mounted my EBS volume. Of course you need to stop and restart the docker daemon for this to take effect.

This is on Amazon Linux. Apparently the docker config file is /etc/default/docker on some Linuxes.